# How can I make model binding bind some properties statically and others dynamically?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

What I mean by this is as follows:

I've got an action method that takes certain fixed properties and then a variable length list of dynamic properties.  I'd like to define a model type like this:

```
    Class MyModel
        Public Id As Integer
        Public Name As String
        Public Fields As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    End Class
```

So if the POST variables look like this:

```
        Id=123&Name=John&field1=abc&field2=def&field3=xyz
```

I want the `Id` and `Name` model fields to be populated, and the remaining fields to go into the `model.Fields` dictionary.

Is that possible?

Comment: I believe you'll need to implement a custom model binder for `MyModel` to accomplish this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx